# JSP is not running

Tags: java, mysql, jsp, tomcat, jdbc

Hi I have created a simple **JSP** file to insert some data into **mysql database** , I have a **tomcat server** running in **localhost with port :9999** , but while running the JSP file it is showing some error , Can anybody help me to solve this , I have tried to run it on eclipse.

giving the error log below

**HTTP Status 500 - An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration.jsp at line 198**

---

type Exception report

message An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration.jsp at line 198

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

exception

org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /registration.jsp at line 198

195: 
 196: PreparedStatement pstatement=null;
 197: 
 198: Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
 199:           int updateQuery = 0;
 200:
 201:           try

**Stacktrace:**

org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.ja
   va:568)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:455)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

**root cause**

javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.doHandlePageException(PageContextImpl.jav
  a:912)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java: 
  841)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:316)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

**root cause**

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1714)
    org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1559)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:126)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperLoader.loadClass(JasperLoader.java:63)
    java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    org.apache.jsp.registration_jsp._jspService(registration_jsp.java:261)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `mysql jar` in your lib folder

Answer (score 0):

See your root cause : `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

It is clearly stated that driver that is required is not found to make connection with database.

You have to include driver for `mysql` in your library.

You can found jar file for same [here](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java).

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you got these two things right

1. You've correctly included corresponding libraries. For example JDBC.

   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
2. Check your SQL statement does not contain any errors.

   PreparedStatement pstatement=null; 197: 198: